# HTML Agility Pack C# - Select cells for a row (not the whole table)

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am using HTML Agility Pack in my Console Application to parse a certain webpage.

I managed to get the table I'm looking for and then select all rows. Up to that point everything works great.

My code looks like following:

```
var rows = table.SelectNodes("//tr");
foreach(var row in rows)
{
    var cells = row.SelectNodes("//td");
    Console.WriteLine(cells.Count);

    foreach(var cell in cells) {
        // Do something
   }
}
```

In each row I should have 4 cells instead I get 697 (the number of cells in the whole table). I tried using `/td .//td` but I would only get an error. Any tips what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second select `//td` selects recursively (two `/`) and from the top (the expression starts with a `/`). What you want is more something like this:

```
var cells = row.SelectNodes(".//td");
```

Which means select recursively from the current context/node (`.`).

See here [XPATH Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) for more on XPATH expressions.

Comment: Problem is whenever I use `/td` or `.//td` I get an error in second loop (I've added more code to the original question). The error says `cells` is `null`

Comment: That's very possible. It entirely depends on your input, as the library returns null when nothing was selected. If you want more help, give us a reproducible scenario.

Comment: I followed the link you gave, of course the dot was correct but my logic flawed. Thanks very much!

Comment: And how did you fix your code? After you added the dot, what did you do to make the original error disappear?